# storing standard output into list groovy

Tags: groovy

I cannot manage to store the standard output from a shell command into a list using the following code.  It seems to store each character as a list element instead of the entire string produced on each line.

```
def implementedBranchName = []

def getImplementedBranches() {
    def cmd = "/usr/bin/tool search status Pending"
    Process process = cmd.execute()
    def output= process .in.text;
    implementedBranchName = output.each{ println it }
    def size = implementedBranchName.size()
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      println(implementedBranchName[i])
    }
}
```

Current Output:

```
F
O
O

B
A
R
```

Desired Output:

```
FOO
BAR
```

Comment: you have declared your `implementedBranchName` as list but you override this parameter as string `def output= process .in.text; implementedBranchName = output.each{ println it }`

Comment: thanks - i ll look into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just change

```
implementedBranchName = output.each{ println it }
```

To:

```
implementedBranchName = output.split()
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also "eachLine" in Groovy.

```
def getImplementedBranches() {
    def cmd = "/usr/bin/tool search status Pending"
    Process process = cmd.execute()
    process.in.eachLine { line ->
        println(line)
    }
}
```